# Intercept the button's event to PDF in objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, events, pdf, adobe-indesign

I have a reader PDF in my iOs's application.

I want to create a button in a pdf. When I click on this button, I want to intercept the event with Objective-c.

What type of button I should use (in Indesign) ?
And How can I intercept the event ?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way to do this and it does not matter what button you use in InDesign.
 After you rendered the page in the view you have to locate the button widgets on the page, they are located in page's Annots collection as widget annotations. Convert the widget's position (Rect entry in widget dictionary) from PDF coordinates to view coordinates. When the user taps on the screen, test if the tap position matches one of your buttons' position.